# Is there something like f-strings in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, variables, string-formatting

Is there a brief way in Kotlin to build formatted strings with variables, similar to f-strings in Python? For example:

`f'My cat is {weight:.1f} pounds.'`

Which would yield:

`My cat is 25.3 pounds.`

Comment: You can either do string interpolation or use `String.format()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is with [`String.format()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/format.html).

It's also an extension method on `String`, so you can call it as follows:

```
"My cat is %.1f pounds.".format(weight)
```

For details, see [this question](/questions/6431933/how-to-format-strings-in-java); the docs for the format patterns are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). (Both are for the Java version, but it's the same in Kotlin.)

Answer (score 0):

As there was no good and multiplatform tool, I wrote MP library that implements a traditional `printf`-like formatting. It is used in many projects, it is simple and works everywhere the same (`.format` worked on JVM only - at least at the time I wrote the library):

https://github.com/sergeych/mp_stools